# unable to list google cloud logging sink for Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I have created a **google cloud logging sink for Bigquery**.  ([Reference](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/exporting-stackdriver-logging-for-security-and-access-analytics#configure_the_logging_export)) And I was able to share the BQ dataset with the Service Account that got created during log creation. And logs are being stored in the BQ dataset tables. But, I am **unable to list the Sink** that I have created. And neither I am able to recreate it nor delete it, Errors out saying sink "Already exists" and sink "does not exist" respectively.

I have admin role. And I hope I have followed instructions well and created the sink. But, still something is missing and I am unable to figure out how the sink itself is missing. Its been almost two days, so looking for guidance. Appreciate your time.

P.s, my first stackoverflow post. sorry if i missed anything.

[Google cloud logging sink listing issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHjTI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to take a look in the storage logs [1] to see if you can locate the issue here.

Also you can try to execute the deletion command using the flags `--organization=ORGANIZATION_ID` and `--project=PROJECT_ID`

for more reference follow the documentation [2].

Cheers,

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/storage#overview

[2] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/sinks/list

Comment: thanks for your time @BraveAdmin. my bad it didn't help